# Unable to find element for schedule an appointment

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaDWF.png)

Attached screen shot of 'schedule an appointment'
Schedule an Appointment

This is a Anchor tag, I am unable to find the exact element and click on 'Schedule an Appointment'.
I have used this to find element

```py
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Schedule").click()
```

Even I have tried with link_text too' Schedule an appointment' . I would appreciate it, if someone can help and provide the solution. Finding very difficult to move.

Many thanks,
Shiva

Comment: Could you add the html to your description as well?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML. Make sure that case is in line with the letter casing in the HTML as well. Just by the look of the image, all is uppercase letters meaning that you need to use

```py
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("SCHEDULE").click()
```

Comment: @Shivakumar please upvote + accept answer if it helped you solve your issue. Thanks!